# Subquery without where-clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Here's my code

```
SELECT res.type, 
       res.contactname, 
       res.id, 
       res.inv_addressline2, 
       res.inv_addressline3, 
       res.signup_date,
       res.engineer_id_global, 
       res.job_id_global, 
       res.neg_or_pos, 
       res.rating, 
       res.author_id_global,
       res.timestamp_global, 
       res.short_description, 
       res.job_title, 
       res.feedback, 
       author_data.contactname AS `author_name`, 
       review_count.total_feedback, 
       review_count.total_rating 
FROM (SELECT mb.type, 
             mb.contactname, 
             mb.id, 
             mb.inv_addressline2, 
             mb.inv_addressline3, 
             mb.signup_date,
             fb.engineer_id AS `engineer_id_global`, 
             fb.timestamp AS `timestamp_global`, 
             fb.job_id AS `job_id_global`, 
             fb.neg_or_pos, 
             fb.rating, 
             fb.feedback, 
             fb.author_id AS `author_id_global`,
             ac.engineer_id, 
             ac.timestamp, 
             ac.author_id,
             jb.job_id, 
             SUBSTR(jb.job_description, 1, 200) AS `short_description`, 
             jb.job_title 
      FROM " . MEMBERS_TABLE . " AS mb 
      LEFT JOIN " . ACCEPTED . " AS ac 
             ON mb.id = ac.engineer_id 
      LEFT JOIN " . FEEDBACK . " AS fb 
             ON ac.job_id = fb.job_id 
      LEFT JOIN " . JOBS . " AS jb 
             ON fb.job_id = jb.job_id 
      WHERE mb.type = 2 
      ORDER BY
            fb.timestamp DESC
     ) AS res 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT mb.id, 
            mb.contactname, 
            fb.author_id 
     FROM " . MEMBERS_TABLE . " AS mb 
     LEFT JOIN " . FEEDBACK . " AS fb 
            ON fb.author_id = mb.id 
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS `author_data`  
       ON res.author_id_global = author_data.author_id 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(fb.engineer_id) AS `total_feedback`, 
            SUM(fb.rating) AS `total_rating`, 
            fb.engineer_id 
     FROM " . FEEDBACK . " AS fb 
    ) AS `review_count` 
       ON res.engineer_id_global = review_count.engineer_id 
GROUP BY res.contactname
ORDER BY res.contactname
```

I'm just starting to get my head around SQL. My worry is the second and third inner query. Am I right in saying it will return *all* results as there is no where clause and the return the results from that using the "ON" statement or is the "ON" statement combined with the initial query?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add comments to the places that you would like us to explain? Just in case you  did not get to the comments syntax in your SQL book yet, SQL comments start with two dashes, and go to the end of the line, like this: `-- this is a SQL comment`.

Comment: - or can spread over multiple lines when enclosed between `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain why they have downvoted? This could enable the OP to improve the question accordingly.

Comment: Just a sidenote, not related to your question. The final `GROUP BY res.contactname ORDER BY res.contactname` can be replaced with `GROUP BY res.contactname ASC` or just `GROUP BY res.contactname`. The order will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this script:

- You have a number of tables with names like `" . MEMBERS_TABLE . "`, `" . ACCEPTED . "` and so on. These are unlikely to be acceptable in MySQL, which normally uses backticks (`) to quote object names; if this script is to be preprocessed by eg. Perl or Python, or is part of a larger script in another language, it would be helpful to say so.
- You have an `order by` clause, for no apparent reason, in your first sub-query. This could be removed.
- Your second sub-query links FEEDBACK to MEMBERS_TABLE and limits the results to 1, without specifying the author_id inside the sub-query - this means that a single, random member will be selected inside the sub-query, then linked to the rest of the dataset on the specific author ID, which won't match for most of the rest of the dataset.

  - The FEEDBACK table is completely irrelevant here, and can be removed.
  - If `id` uniquely identifies a record on MEMBERS_TABLE, the sub-query can be completely removed and replaced with a single left join to MEMBERS_TABLE on `res.author_id_global = MEMBERS_TABLE.id`. No `limit` clause would be required.
  - If `id` does not uniquely identify a record on MEMBERS_TABLE, the sub-query should be rewritten as `select distinct id, contact_name FROM " . MEMBERS_TABLE . " AS mb where res.author_id_global = mb.id LIMIT 1`. If there are multiple matching authors for the same `id`, one would be selected at random.
- The third sub-query does not require a `where` clause - it will summarise all engineers' feedback and ratings by engineer within the sub-query, and each engineer will then be linked to the corresponding engineer from the rest of the dataset by the `on` condition from the `left join` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Second inner query is having limit 1. It is nothing but where condition to show only one result. Third inner query is not having any problem.